# How to extend a LSTM model to probabilistic Bayesian LSTM model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I have an LSTM model for regression in Python and I wanna extend it to Probabilistic Bayesian LSTM. In fact, I wanna learn the probability distribution of outputs. If I wanna map output to Normal distribution, is it possible to provide confidence interval for both mean and variance?

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(100, activation='relu', return_sequences=True, input_shape=(n_steps_in, n_features)))
model.add(LSTM(100, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(n_steps_out))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')

# fit model
model.fit(X, y, epochs=100, verbose=1)
```

Comment: your output isn't your number of steps out, each output neuron should be probability of each class, you don't need to do anything to it. and what do you mean when you say mean and variance? mean and variance of what? the output probability?

Comment: Yes. I want to predict the mean and variance of outputs. Actually, it predicts `n_steps_out` periods ahead. It just provides a point prediction, but I want to predict a normal distribution for each point and mean and variance are determined through LSTM.

Comment: I still don't understand what you actually want to accomplish. if you want your output to also have a sequence of probabilities for each point, you should define it as LSTM (or other sequence layers like CRF, GRU etc.) maybe tell us what is your model input, and what do you want it to predict?

Comment: Currently, I am using the "Multi-Step LSTM Models - Vector Output Model" model in https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-develop-lstm-models-for-time-series-forecasting/. However, the prediction of this model for a sample is something like [[100.98096 113.28924]]. However, it is point prediction. Instead of 100.98096, I want to also predict the variance of  the first element. 
This idea for general NN is used in :
https://keras.io/examples/keras_recipes/bayesian_neural_networks/
Experiment 3: probabilistic Bayesian neural network

Comment: There is no built-in probabilistic LSTM layer in TFP. So you need to combine a few things to get it work. Like in normal LSTM, you need to replace weights with prior & posterior distributions. Or you can use `tfp.stats`.